# How to draw transparent image in java with BufferedImage?

Tags: java, canvas, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm willing to show an transparent image on a canvas in java with the help of graphics2D and BufferedImage.

Here is the code which loads image.

```
private static BufferedImage sprites,board;
    public static void load(){
        try {
            board = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            board = ImageIO.read(new File("res/chesssprite.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SpriteManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

and here is the code which renders the image

```
public void render(){

        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        {

            g2d.setColor(new Color(150,150,150));
            g2d.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            g2d.drawImage(board,0,0,null);

        }
        g = g2d;
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
```

I have search on net a lot but didn't come with an solution. If anyone knowns how to fix this.

Here is the image..
[image]

And here is how output looks like

[image]

Comment: That is not a transparent image.  It appears to be *based* on a transparent image, but the image you are using has an opaque gray checkerboard pattern as its background (which typically is used by image editors and viewers to visually indicate transparent areas).

Comment: @VGR I think it is transparent  not sure though. If you can tell me how to make it transparent

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer to that on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com.  Personally, I would use GIMP’s Fuzzy Select tool to select and clear the checkerboard area.

Comment: @VGR Okay! now I made it transparent but the output is hilarious!! It is now showing black color wherever there is transparency.. One step closer to solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay whoever facing these kind of problem:

1. Make sure the image is transparent. Test it in image viewer.
2. Remove the line `g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);` This line adds alpha composites which make every transparent pixel black.